# Use @StateObject owned by child view as @ObservedObject in sibling views

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the examples I've found so far, @StateObject variables are owned by a parent view, and then passed on to children views which in turn use them as @ObservedObject.
However, this seems to have the side effect that when the @StateObject is updated, other the views in the hierarchy are also re-created and/or re-rendered - even views that do not reference the @ObservedObject themselves.

Instead, I'd like to create a @StateObject in (some of) the children views -i.e. children views would be the owners of their own @StateObject, and then other "sibling" views would use these objects as @ObservedObject.

For simplicity, I've attached a playground that (hopefully) portrays what I'm trying to do.

When a `ChildView` changes the value in its own @StateObject, ideally, only the `ChildView` and its associated `SiblingView` would be re-created and/or re-rendered. The `StaticView`s, ideally, should not be re-created and/or re-rendered.

Each of these views print a few lines to the console to indicate when they're being created/re-created and rendered/re-rendered.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ParentView: View {
        
    init() {
        print("ParentView init")
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        if printWithinBody("ParentView rendering body\n") {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach((1...3), id: \.self) {
                        StaticView(id: $0)
                            .padding(5)
                    }
                }
                HStack {
                    ForEach((1...3), id: \.self) { viewID in
                        VStack {
                            
                            let childView = ChildView(initialValue: Int.random(in: 1...5), id: viewID)
                            childView
                                .padding(5)
                        
                            SiblingView(observedStateObject: childView.stateObject, id: viewID)
                                .padding(5)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StaticView: View, Identifiable {

    var id: Int

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        print("StaticView\(id) - init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        if printWithinBody("StaticView\(id) - rendering body\n") {
            Text("Static\(id)")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .border(.gray, width: 2)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View, Identifiable {

    @StateObject var stateObject: MySharedStateObject
    var id: Int

    init(initialValue: Int, id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        _stateObject = StateObject(wrappedValue: MySharedStateObject(initialValue: initialValue))
        print("ChildView\(id) - init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        if printWithinBody("ChildView\(id) - rendering body") {
            Text("Child\(id) owned val \(stateObject.sharedValue)")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .border(.green, width: 2)
                .onTapGesture {
                    stateObject.sharedValue += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SiblingView: View, Identifiable {
    
    @ObservedObject var observedStateObject: MySharedStateObject
    var id: Int

    init(observedStateObject: MySharedStateObject, id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.observedStateObject = observedStateObject
        print("SiblingView\(id) - init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        if printWithinBody("SiblingView\(id) - rendering body\n") {
            Text("Sibling\(id) observed val \(observedStateObject.sharedValue)")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .border(.blue, width: 2)
        }
    }
}

class MySharedStateObject: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    
    @Published var sharedValue: Int
    
    init(initialValue: Int = Int.zero) {
        sharedValue = initialValue
    }
    static func == (lhs: MySharedStateObject, rhs: MySharedStateObject) -> Bool {
        return lhs.sharedValue == rhs.sharedValue
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func printWithinBody(_ message: String) -> Bool {
        print(message)
        return true
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ParentView())
```

As it is, the code above does not raise any compile issues, but the `SiblingView`s don't seem to be receiving updates from the @ObservedObject.

I have attempted these changes in `SiblingView` initialization:

```
struct SiblingView: View, Identifiable {

    @ObservedObject var observedStateObject: MySharedStateObject
    var id: Int

    init(observedStateObject: ObservedObject<MySharedStateObject>, id: Int) { //changes introduced here
        self.id = id
        self._observedStateObject = observedStateObject //and here
        print("SiblingView\(id) - init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        if printWithinBody("SiblingView\(id) - rendering body\n") {
            Text("Sibling\(id) observed val \(observedStateObject.sharedValue)")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .border(.blue, width: 2)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when creating a `SiblingView` from within the `ParentView`:

#1 if I leave the code unchanged:

```
SiblingView(observedStateObject: childView.stateObject, id: viewID)
```

I get this error:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:27:72: error: cannot convert value of type 'MySharedStateObject' to expected argument type 'ObservedObject<MySharedStateObject>'
                            SiblingView(observedStateObject: childView.stateObject, id: viewID)
                                                                       ^
```

#2 and if I change that to:

```
SiblingView(observedStateObject: childView.$stateObject, id: viewID)
```

I get this error:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:27:72: error: cannot convert value of type 'ObservedObject<MySharedStateObject>.Wrapper' to expected argument type 'ObservedObject<MySharedStateObject>'
                            SiblingView(observedStateObject: childView.$stateObject, id: viewID)
                                                                       ^
```

Hopefully some of you may have already find a way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since the SiblingView isn’t created from the ChildView but at the same level it only makes sense to have the @StateObject in the ParentView or to create the SiblingView inside the ChildView

Comment: @loremipsum I don't think that's necessarily true. Using `init` to create a `StateObject` is generally fine (confirmed to me by SwiftUI engineers in a WWDC lab session) as the `wrappedValue` parameter uses an `autoclosure` and only runs in the event that the newly init-ed `View` is actually added to the hierarchy. You can test this by adding a `print` statement to your `ObservableObject`'s init and see that it only gets called once even though the View's `init` may get called many times.

Comment: Thank you @Joakim, that's what I had seen in pretty much every other article, tut, video, etc. - however, I think there should be a way to let sibling views observe the state owned by other sibling views (without involving the parent view). The actual app will potentially have hundreds/thousands of these sibling views, and the observed state will include position during drag operations. So, re-creating/re-rendering all other sibling views, even those not involved in the particular action the user is taking, just because we've made the parent view the owner of the state, seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: Thank you @jnpdx, your insights do reinforce what I've seen in other articles. I'm hoping SO will let me post the URL for this article - I think it would be useful for the community.
https://www.mattmoriarity.com/2020-07-03-stateobject-and-observableobject-in-swiftui/ ... it did =)